# Pagination with Redis sets vs sorted sets

Tags: pagination, redis

We are storing users and friends (relationships) in Redis sets.
This is probably easy but we can't figure out how to get back results when paginating.
Example: when showing a logged in users's friends, we need the first 20 results, then on the following click, the next 20 results, etc.. We don't really care about the order, provided we don't get repeated data for the following queries.
We prefer to use sets vs sorted sets, as sets lets us use cheap SINTER for other queries.
WHat would the recommended aproach be? Storing them as both sets and sorted sets? Sounds a bit redundant.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I meant SINTER. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You can paginate through a Set using `SSCAN`, note that it can return the same result twice though. Alternatively, Sorted Sets are the best for that kind of task. Lastly, Lists can also work but `LRANGE` is an expensive operation.

Comment: Thanks. We certainly cannot get the same result twice since it would be confusing. What would the correct way to paginate be when using sorted sets? We have found no equivalent to SSCAN or LRANGE for sorted sets.

Comment: Have you looked at `ZRANGE`, `ZRANGEBYSCORE` and the rest of the the gang?